# Can I use Xamarin with NokiaX

Tags: xamarin, nokiax

Since Nokia X (and X+ and XL) is based on Android and Xamarin supports Android, can we use Xamarin to build applications for the new Nokia X phones?

Or is this a different breed of Android.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nokia X (and X+ and XL) is built upon the Android Project V4.1.2 (Level 16). Yes, it's compatible with Xamarin.Android and you just have to select the proper API level.

It's also interesting to know that Nokia uses Xamarin and MVVM Cross for Nokia X's pre-installed apps.

> One example of this is the Nokia MixRadio app, which started its life
>   as a Windows Phone and Windows Store application and using the power
>   of the Xamarin platform, is shipping as a pre-installed app on Nokia X
>   devices. To make the most of their existing applications, they
>   maximised the use of shared code with Portable Class Libraries and the
>   popular third party MVVM library MVVMCross whilst still taking
>   advantage of the Nokia X platform’s nuances and user interface.

Here the [official post](http://blog.xamarin.com/nokia-x-for-csharp/) from Xamarin.

Comment: I can confirm that Xamarin applications work. If there is any doubt then head over to Nokia site and run run the compatibility test, then fire up one of the hardwares on their remote test site to run it on an actual device: http://developer.nokia.com/nokia-x/get-started

Answer (score 2):

Nokia X service APIs (maps, payment and notification) have also been implemented as free Xamarin components.

https://components.xamarin.com/?search=Nokia

Please also note that Xamarin.Android version 4.12.0 or higher is required!